# Unable to parse javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can get values from this type of object using javascript or jquery

```
    {
        authResponse: {
            userID: "12345678912345",
            accessToken:"kgkh3g42kh4g23kh4g2kh34g2kg4k2h4gkh3g4k2h4gk23h4gk2h34gk234gk2h34AndSoOn",
            session_Key: true,
            expiresIn: "5183738",
            sig: "..."
        },
        status: "connected"
    }
```

I want to get value of session key from this object. I tried parsing it in JSON but this is invalid JSON format and when i tried to get value using obj.key It returns undefined. I am getting this response in return while checking session. Please go through below link for more details

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/a5c6be9/README.md

Comment: Have you tried anything? What values you want to access?

Comment: I guess this page may help you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.stringify({
    authResponse: {
        userID: "12345678912345",
        accessToken: "kgkh3g42kh4g23kh4g2kh34g2kg4k2h4gkh3g4k2h4gk23h4gk2h34gk234gk2h34AndSoOn",
        session_Key: true,
        expiresIn: "5183738",
        sig: "..."
    },
    status: "connected"
});

alert(obj.authResponse.userID); //"12345678912345"
alert(obj.status); //"connected"
```

Comment: You might want to explain a bit, since the question is easy and OP is naive

Comment: Hi!, It is saying userID is undefined. I am getting this as response when i check facebook session. Here is the link 
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/a5c6be9/README.md

Comment: what does `alert(obj.status)` say?

Comment: JSON.stringyfy did the trick 

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access the values from each level:-

```
myobj =  {
        authResponse: {
            userID: "12345678912345",
            accessToken:"kgkh3g42kh4g23kh4g2kh34g2kg4k2h4gkh3g4k2h4gk23h4gk2h34gk234gk2h34AndSoOn",
            session_Key: true,
            expiresIn: "5183738",
            sig: "..."
        },
        status: "connected"
    }


alert(myobj.authResponse.userID);//"12345678912345"
alert(myobj.status);//"connected"
```

**if key is numeric use arry notation `[]` otherwise dot(`.`) can help you to access the child.**

Comment: I tried both , none of them worked.